# APIError(code=-2010): The relationship of the prices for the orders is not correct. BInance Python

Tags: python, bots, trading, binance

I am using a  python program to trade in VS code , but I have a problem in oco sell order, for example the price of FTM in USDT is 1.51143181$ I chose the price is 1.5174 and limit price 1.5084 and stop limit price is 1.4933 but I have This error when I run my program:API Error (code=-2010): The relationship of the prices for the orders is not correct.
i know that the price must be > than the limite price and must be > stop limite price .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Price Restrictions:
SELL: Limit Price > Last Price > Stop Price
BUY: Limit Price < Last Price < Stop Price

Please read https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#new-oco-trade 221 to confirm the details;
If you still have question, please share the exact request, especially the limit price, last price and stop price for further analysis

Comment: I have found something by trying this in the Binance trader tool - it gives a more useful error "Price should be less than market price - This is likely my root cause. I don’t know if it’s anyone else’s